# Convert possible UTF-8 to proper string

Tags: ruby, string, utf-8, ascii

I have a string like:

```
a = "@\n\u001E\rANSI 636000410225ZM02660027DLDCA\nDCB\nDCD\nDBA04052024\nDCSKILLER01-21-2014\nZMB01\n\r"
```

I'm following this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263271/converting-utf8-to-ansi-with-ruby) for fix, but no matter what I try, the `\u001E` doesn't get resolved to proper string.

What am I doing wrong?

**Sample Output**

```
=> a.unpack("U*").map{|c|c.chr}.join

=> "@\n\x1E\rANSI 636000410225ZM02660027DLDCA\nDCB\nDCD\nDBA04052024\nDCSKILLER01-21-2014\nZMB01\n\r"
```

Same output for: `a.encode('ASCII')`

Any suggestions?

Comment: It’s not clear what you want to do here. `\u001E` already is an ASCII character. It is the control character “Record Separator”. In both ASCII and UTF-8 it consists of the single byte `0x1E`. Ruby will display it as either `\u001E` if the string has UTF-8 encoding and as `\x1E` if the string has ASCII (or binary) encoding.

Comment: @matt How to get rid of it without using manual ways like `gsub`? In the entire string, that is the only unwanted portion.

Comment: Just using `gsub` (or `sub` if there’s only one of these characters) is probably the way to go here. Theres nothing really special about `\u001E`, it’s just a character like any other, albeit a non printing one.